# Java static variable is assigned null value

Tags: java

Below is my code, wondering why null is printed instead of Hello World!!!

```
public class MyClass {

    static String s1 = getMyValue();
    static String s2 = "Hello World!!!";

    private static String getMyValue() {
        return s2;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.print(s1);  //outputs: null
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to place s2 initialization before s1 .

Comment: Initialized by order of declaration. So `s1` gets assigned to `getMyValue()` which returns `null` since `s2` hasn't been assigned yet.

Comment: I haven't touched Java in a long time but don't you need to reference inner function using `this.getMyValue()` seemed like a common usage in C#, PHP and as far as I recall Java. May be something has changed. Anyone can shed some light onto this? Actually, class properties to be assigned using another method would usually be performed within a constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this in a debugger and you wil see that s1=getMyValue() is executed BEFORE s2 is set to "Hello World!!!"..

Comment: Right, however why doesn't it give error on return s2, since it didn't find s2 and s2 is defined after s1.

Comment: @MaheshSapkal The compiler won't parse every single possible path to figure out who called `getMyValue` and if it's defined before whatever value is used within the method.